# Python QSqlRelation

Tags: python, qsqltablemodel, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

I am using a QtableView to display data from a QSqlRelationalTableModel which seems to work fine, however when I use
`self.motormodel.setRelation(1, QSqlRelation('Instruments', "Asset Tag","Description" )) self.ui.motorTableView.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.ui.motorTableView))`

to create a QSqlRelationalDelegate on the view and I try and sort the columns using the header of a column in the tableView the table doesn't refresh and I lose the model data in the view.

If I comment out the
`self.motormodel.setRelation(1, QSqlRelation('Instruments', "Asset Tag","Description" ))`
then it works as expected and the sort works.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why are you creating a relationship on the view? it is in the model if ever. Is assettag the foreign key?